# String matching and bioinformatics

Tags: reference-request, bioinformatics, string-matching

I'm interestd in string-matching, I would like to know recent open problems in string-matching in field of bioinformatics.

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of question is typically not a good fit for this site. You can ask a researcher in the field.

Comment: I don't know any researcher, Is there a site for this kind of questions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of open problems in bioinformatics: string matching is outlined in [Some string matching problems from Bioinformatics which still need better solutions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866703000625) this article is old, but problems remain.
There is also presentation [Analytic pattern matching: From DNA to Twitter](http://www.aofa.tcs.uj.edu.pl/presentations/06-07-2016-szpankowski.pdf).

Some are related to graph automorphism (so may remain open for a bit longer) for example:

> Extend String Pattern Matching to Graph Pattern Matching, that is, replace the text T by a graph G and find the number of occurrences of a given subgraph/pattern *g* in G for different models of graph G generation.